# How to re-render component after saga dispatches to redux store

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga, rerender

I am using react hooks & redux hooks.

I have a component that checks redux for state. If the state is not there it will perform a `useDispatch` to fetch the books needed.

Inside the saga, there are a variety of functions but I just posted the last bit that saves to the store as this is the issue I'm trying to grasp.

The saga successfully pushes to the store (the redux dev tools shows the new state) but the component does not rerender when the new state is posted.

Any clues here?

`myComponent.js`

```
  const topBooks = useSelector(state => state.BOOKS[TOP_BOOKS]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (!topBooks) {
    dispatch(fetchTopBooks(TOP_BOOKS));
  }

  return (
    <Shelf>
      <Books books={topBooks} />
    </Shelf>
  );
}
```

`bookSaga.js`

```
function* saveBooks() {
  while (true) {
    const { payload } = yield take(SAVE_BOOKS);

    yield put({
      type: SET_TOP_BOOKS,
      payload
    });
  }
}
```

`bookReducer.js`

```
const initialState = {};

const actionMap = {
  [SET_TOP_BOOKS](state, action) {
    return {
      TOP_BOOKS: action.payload
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: You're sometimes using TOP_BOOKS as though it's a variable (eg, `state.BOOKS[TOP_BOOKS]`), and sometimes as a literal string (eg,  `return { TOP_BOOKS: action.payload};`. Is that intentional? If so, what's the value of the variable?

Comment: @NicholasTower that did it!! Overlooked that small detail. Thank you!